# How do I use the robot class to draw islands inside a two dimensional array?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that will take control of my mouse for me, and draw an island created by an array in one go, however I have no clue how to begin this, or if it is possible. I included an example of a type of island in a two dimensional array. The actual array would contain numbers from 0-63, and therefore have 64 types of islands. The image is simplified.

[example of an island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfmdg.png)
[Another type of island](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPs4x.png)

I am not sure on how to even begin and came here to ask for a plan on how to draw these types of islands in one go. I already have the two dimensional array, I just want to know how to make my mouse control it.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments. Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Also consider `TexturePaint`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bswing%5d%20TexturePaint).

Comment: You are welcome; if this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.